# Postgresql - ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory

Tags: windows, postgresql, python-2.7

When I run

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu;
```

on my Postgresql, I get

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory
```

I installed Python 2.7.16 - https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.16/python-2.7.16.amd64.msi
Then https://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-11.2-1-windows-x64.exe

If I search for plpython2 on entire disk, it isn't found. But I have also python 3 and plpython3 is found. I tried to reinstalled both postgresql installation and python but no luck.

I searched for this error but no solution worked.
(If I run create language plpython2u; I get the same error.)

I also tried to run

```
create language plpython3u;
```

to see if that would work but i need to use python2. This one fails on

```
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not be found.

SQL state: XX000
```

but the file exists and postgresql definitely has full access to the file.

Any ideas, hints how I can make python 2 running on postgresql on Windows 10?

Many thanks